# Why am I endlessly appending a String in Java

Tags: java

I was writing a game, and when I try to send a chat message to the server, I get an odd memory leak.
Sending string:
!chat¥Test
Turns into:

```
!chat¥test
!chat¥!chat¥test
!chat¥!chat¥!chat¥test
!chat¥!chat¥!chat¥!chat¥test
!chat¥!chat¥!chat¥!chat¥!chat¥test
!chat¥!chat¥!chat¥!chat¥!chat¥!chat¥test
!chat¥!chat¥!chat¥!chat¥!chat¥!chat¥!chat¥test
!chat¥!chat¥!chat¥!chat¥!chat¥!chat¥!chat¥!chat¥test
!chat¥!chat¥!chat¥!chat¥!chat¥!chat¥!chat¥!chat¥!chat¥test
!chat¥!chat¥!chat¥!chat¥!chat¥!chat¥!chat¥!chat¥!chat¥!chat¥test
!chat¥!chat¥!chat¥!chat¥!chat¥!chat¥!chat¥!chat¥!chat¥!chat¥!chat¥test
Ect, ect.


Sending message:

Utils.sendChat(message.getText());

public static void sendChat(String s) {
    System.out.println(s);
    sendChat("!chat"+Wrapper.commandSplit+s);
}

public static void sendTextLine(String s){
    s = s.replace(" ", "[SPACE]");
    System.out.println(s);
    Wrapper.pw.write(s);
     Wrapper.pw.flush();
}
```

I have no Idea why this is happening, can somebody help me?
I use the '¥' to split variables in the string, and has not given me any issues before, so I doubt it has anything to do with it.

Thanks.

Comment: How does the getText work? It could be that you are appending on the same text and not a memory leak but a scope issue with the text you tell the server to send.

Comment: Two things...most people use commas to delimit and I'm pretty sure you're just recursively calling sendChat.

Comment: Endless loop does not belong to the class of memory leak problems.

Comment: @chaitanya10: please improve your english. "ur" is for teenboppers texting on cellphones. SO is not going to run out of disk space and blow up because someone dared waste space with "your".

Comment: @MarcB haha, i commented from mobile.. :P

Comment: @MarcB it's actually "English" not "english"

Answer (score 10):

```
public static void sendChat(String s) {
    System.out.println(s);
    sendChat("!chat"+Wrapper.commandSplit+s);
}
```

That is an endless loop building longer and longer strings each time you call `sendChat` again.

You probably meant to call `sendTextLine` on the second line there?

Comment: I hope user1681891 comes back and marks this as correct...until then have a +1

Comment: don't get your hopes up, 0% acccept rate